# Move the "Recently Viewed Products" widget in magento

Tags: php, xml, magento, widget, product

The xml code that I have for the widget layout is this:

```
    <reference name="left">
            <block type="catalog/product_compare_sidebar" before="cart_sidebar" name="catalog.compare.sidebar" template="catalog/product/compare/sidebar.phtml"/>
            <block type="core/text_list" name="left.permanent.callout" template="callouts/left_col.phtml">
                <!--<action method="setImgSrc"><src>images/media/col_left_callout.jpg</src></action>
                <action method="setImgAlt" translate="alt" module="catalog"><alt>Our customer service is available 24/7. Call us at (555) 555-0123.</alt></action>-->
                <block type="cms/block" name="left_callout">
                    <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>left_callout</block_id></action>
                </block>
                <action method="setLinkUrl"><url>checkout/cart</url></action>
            </block>
    </reference>
```

And the corresponding output that I get is that the products get shown below the menu and above the product.
I want the recently viewed product widget below the main product and if possible below the "You may also like section".
The layout of the page is 1column layout.
Please help. What to do????

Comment: In your view file there will be a `$this->getChildHtml('cart_sidebar');` Moving that code will move the block.

Comment: There is nothing like that. It is called via $this->getChildHtml('content');

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure but from what I know you can do something like this:

xml file (I think catalog.xml)

```
<reference name="content"><block type="catalog/product_compare_sidebar" after="" name="catalog.compare.sidebar" template="catalog/product/compare/sidebar.phtml"/>
        <block type="core/text_list" name="left.permanent.callout" template="callouts/left_col.phtml">
            <block type="cms/block" name="left_callout">
                <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>left_callout</block_id></action>
            </block>
            <action method="setLinkUrl"><url>checkout/cart</url></action>
        </block></reference>
```

On the after="" tag, type in the name of the block for the related products(you may also like). You can find it somewhere in the xml file also. That would tell the Recently Viewed block to appear only after you may also like.

Then, in your 1 column html, call it using $this->getChildHtml('left.permanent.callout'); right after where the other child html's are called.